# Grammar of captions

Tags: sentence-construction, headlinese

My question was closed on English Language and Usage.
So I am asking it here.

Can anybody explain to me the sentence structure of captions.

Do captions have to be grammatical?
If yes What kind of sentences are these?

**Booking started**

**Admissions open**

Are these some kind of abbreviations?

Answer (score 5):

**Do** captions have to be grammatical?

No, they don't. They are like [newspaper headlines](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-headlinese-1690921), which are written in the smallest number of words necessary to get the meaning across.

Comment: I disagree. They have to be grammatical - it's just that their grammar is different from (any) standard English grammar. Word salad like "showing Smith picture John a" is not grammatical.

Comment: As the professor in the linked article says 'they move on the fringe of ordinary grammar'.

Comment: As do various dialects of English. Again, they have their own grammar.

Comment: They have to be grammatical but they can be shortened or have gaps in words: Admissions [are] open.

Answer (score 1):

Captions/headlines are different genre than complete sentences. Some things that are mandatory in complete sentences are optional in this genre. "Booking started" could be short for "Booking has started". Search for "headlinese" for more information.